# Celery: What is the difference between rejecting and retrying?

Tags: python, celery

I was reading the Celery docs in detail on Reject and retrying tasks (link [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#reject)). What is the difference between calling `raise self.retry(exc=exc)` and simply calling `raise Reject(exc, requeue=True)`?  If you are going to requeue a task when rejecting, is there any difference between the two? Why would you do one over the other?

This is particularly confusing because the docs issue an explicit infinite loop warning for `Reject`, but not for `self.retry()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you retry a task, like this

```
raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

it will retry only 3 times(default). You can also specify number of times you want to retry like this.

```
raise self.retry(exc=exc, max_retries=10)
```

This will retry at max 10 times **only**.

On the other hand, when you reject and reque it, you might enter into infinite loop as there is **no maximum limit**.

If you are fetching data from a 3rd party service, you can use retry. This will make sure that you get the data even if 3rd party service is down for few seconds.

I haven't used `Reject` anywhere. Let's say, you want to connect to port `8000` on your server and there are some other process which will be connecting to same port occasionally.

Now in your task, you can try to connect to port and if some process are using that port, you can simply reject it and requeue it. This will happen until the other process stops listening to 8000 and you task will be executed eventually.

But you have to make sure, you will get a chance to execute the task successfully else you will end up in limbo.

Comment: We're use a semaphore to manage resources and prevent there from being too many database connections. If the semaphore isn't acquired, then reject is used. However, you cannot reject and requeue if acks_late isn't true.